# Add and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with changing classes in jQuery. I'm working on an admin system where I can set a status of items on and off. I visualize this by showing a red and green icon. So the classes with the red items must by change to green by clicking and the greens must be red by clicking. My problem is that the second time clicking the class change does not work anymore.

This is my html:

```
<ul id="sections">
   <li class="on">Item</li>
   <li class="on">Item</li>
   <li class="on">Item</li>
   <li class="on">Item</li>
</ul>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
$("li.on").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('off').removeClass('on');
});

$("li.off").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on').removeClass('off');  
});


});
```

And my CSS styles the "on" and "off" classes.

Comment: Keep in mind that `$("li.on")` and `$("li.off")` are only evaluated in the `ready` function, not later on, and you should be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you bind to the elements based on the classes they have at binding time. And initially `$("li.off")` is empty.

Use

```
$(function(){
    $('#sections')
    .on('click', "li.on", function() {
        $(this).addClass('off').removeClass('on');
    })
    .on('click', "li.off", function() {
        $(this).addClass('on').removeClass('off');  
    });
});
```

You might be interested in [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) too, which would allow you do do this :

```
$(function(){
    $('#sections').on('click', "li", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('off on');
    });
});
```

Comment: **+1** Perfect, and for second solution, simply `$(this).toggleClass('on off');`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `toggleClass` that does exactly what you want.

This is all the code you need:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    $('li.on, li.off').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('on off');
    });
});
```

And I created a fiddle for you to see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/nHyHd/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple and elegant

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('#sections li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on off');
 });
});
```

Comment: I cant't because my reputation is not high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass()

For Demo and codes please check http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-toggleclass-example/

(Please scroll to the bottom of the page. toggle() and remove class method is described with example and also there is a working demo )